# image not showing in launchscreen

Tags: ios, launch-screen

I have an old project and convert into `swift 3`. It have simple `launch screen storyboard` . `Launch screen storyboard` have an image as logo of company, This image not showing into device but i replace that image with another image , **replaced image** showing **perfect**. `Launch screen` behave strange.

Comment: Can't reproduce unless you provide the problematic image and explain how you are showing it. — However, please note that you are using the launch screen incorrectly in any case. It is _not_ to be used as a splash screen.

Comment: @matt could you explain what the difference is between a launch screen and a splash screen? And why you wouldn't want to use the launch screen as such?

Comment: @DanielLegler Read what Apple says about what the launch screen is for. https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/launch-screen/ Look at their example: it is effectively just a blank version of the actual initial screen. "The launch screen isn’t a branding opportunity. Don’t design an entry experience that looks like a splash screen or an "About" window. Don’t include logos or other branding elements unless they’re a static part of your app’s first screen."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just delete launch screen storyboard and make a new launch screen storyboard then new image view on it .Make sure your image size 1x,2x,3x available.